# How to resolve INSERT contention in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: partitioning, azure-sql-database, insert, logging, timeout

I'm working with an Azure SQL Database that has a very hot logging table. Any time a row in any other table is inserted, updated, or deleted, the web application writes a row to this logging table. The rows are very small and there is only one NC index and the PK on the table, but these inserts can stack up and sometimes even timeout, and the application then has to use its exponential back-off retry logic.

The architect decided to implement partitioning on this logging table to resolve the insert speed problem. Every table has ProjectId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) as part of the PK. He added a BIGINT IDENTITY ProjectNo column to the Project table, and the partitioning function looks up the ProjectNo for the ProjectId and then uses ProjectNo % 200 to pick which partition all rows for that project use.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChangeLog](
    [IncrementId]           [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId]             [uniqueidentifier]      NOT NULL,
    [ProjectNoPartitionKey] [tinyint]               NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]             [int]                   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn]             [datetime2](0)          NOT NULL,
    [EntityId]              [uniqueidentifier]      NULL, -- but no null values
    [EntityName]            [varchar](50)           NULL, -- but no null values
    [RevisionId]            [uniqueidentifier]      NULL,
    [RootId]                [uniqueidentifier]      NULL,
    [Status]                [tinyint]               NOT NULL,
    [OperationType]         [tinyint]               NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ChangeLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IncrementId] ASC,
    [ProjectNoPartitionKey] ASC,
    [ProjectId] ASC
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ChangeLog_ProjectNoPartitionKey_ProjectId_EntityName_IncrementId_INCLUDE_All] ON [dbo].[ChangeLog]
(
    [ProjectNoPartitionKey] ASC,
    [ProjectId] ASC,
    [EntityName] ASC,
    [IncrementId] ASC
)
INCLUDE([EntityId],[RootId],[RevisionId],[Status],[OperationType],[CreatedBy],[CreatedOn]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF);
```

Unfortunately, there is a huge amount of skew in the number of rows in the logging table between projects. The largest 4 partitions of the 200 have 25% of all the rows in the logging table. So while it reduced the timeout frequency, they still occur often enough to be a concern. The table is written to around 175x as often as it is read from.

It doesn't seem likely that increasing the number of partitions will be of much help. I've been told that making the logging table in-memory would be the best solution, but none of us have used that feature. Suggestions?

Comment: `The table is written to around 175x as often as it is read from` -- Why do you need indexes at all, then? Since your PK leads with an identity column, you might want to look at [optimize for sequential key](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/optimize_for_sequential_key/enabling-optimize-for-sequential-key/).

Comment: @ErikDarling The NC index is read by SPs that purge outdated rows. The table has about 4 million rows. Jason Strate's sp_IndexAnalysis recommends realigning the PK. The NC index is read from far more often than the PK. Instead of using OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY, I'm going to suggest changing the PK order match the NC index (keyed on ProjectNoPartitionKey, ProjectId, EntityName, IncrementId and INCLUDEs all other columns) and dropping the NC index. The PK will then have 200 possible values as the first key instead of an IDENTITY. It at least seems worth testing. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Do you know whether the slowness was caused by lock contention, latch contention, or IO waits?  If not, every design change is premature as they have different solutions.  And why introduce a new partition key instead of simply partitioning by projectid?

Comment: You shouldn't just guess.  Wait stats will tell you.  Latch contention normally becomes noticeable over a few thousand inserts/sec.   You can split big partitions (not free), and create dedicated partitions for selected ProjectId values.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Query Store is showing a Wait Category of Lock. The issue with partitioning directly on ProjectId is that it is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, with values created from many sources (thousands of laptops running Express Edition that sync to the Azure SQL Database). So even though they are created using NewSequentialId, there isn't a good way to partition on them. Even if we did, we would still likely have the problem of a few partitions having most of the rows.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The problem with creating dedicated partitions for specific ProjectId values is that we have about 150 databases (one per company) deployed with identical schemas, so I need a solution that won't involve different partitioning functions for each one.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest modifying your PK to use `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` (as suggested by [Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) in [the comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305074/how-to-resolve-insert-contention-in-azure-sql-database?noredirect=1#comment595567_305074).

[Enabling Optimize For Sequential Key](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/optimize_for_sequential_key/enabling-optimize-for-sequential-key/) is pretty straightforward. This makes it a relatively low-effort, low-impact starting point.

```sql
ALTER INDEX PK_ChangeLog 
    ON dbo.ChangeLog SET(OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY  = ON);
```

This feature was made specifically to address the scenario you're seeing--so before re-clustering the table and fighting those higher-effort, higher-risk changes, using the purpose built setting first is the right starting point! There's no guarantee it will be a silver bullet to solve your problem, but it should help.

Pam Lahoud, from the SQL Server Product Group wrote a great [behind the scenes article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/behind-the-scenes-on-optimize-for-sequential-key/ba-p/806888) on the feature. From Pam's article:

> With last page insert contention, as the number of insert threads increases, the queue for the page latch increases which in turn increases latency. Throughput will also decrease, but if something slows down one of the threads that is holding the latch, this can trigger a convoy and throughput suddenly falls off a cliff.
>
> ...
>
> When using this option, you may not see a decrease in PAGELATCH waits, in fact you may even see an increase in waits with a new wait type called BTREE_INSERT_FLOW_CONTROL. Despite these waits, you should be able to achieve much better throughput, and scale to a much higher number of concurrent threads, without hitting the proverbial cliff.

If you are still seeing limited throughput after enabling that feature, you may then need to resort to changing your indexing strategy to eliminate that "last page contention" when concurrent inserts are all clamoring to write to the end of the table.

Comment: Only if the timeouts were due to latch contention, which isn't at all clear.  Could well be IO waits caused by the guid keys.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://youtu.be/BLcdN-d59o0) may be a little overkill for your case (even if you're on Azure some concepts still applies), but if you care about the fastest INSERT possible it's a very interesting talk.

Check out their other [sessions](https://eightkb.online/previous/) as well, you may find something useful there.